# How to write source information for tables if I'm using data from multiple sources?

Tags: publications, citations, writing, citation-style, tables

I am using data from 3-4 different sources in my table. How to cite the source information in MLA format? As far as I know, Source information is written below tables in the MLA style. But is it okay to mention multiple sources below the table? Won't it look cluttered?

Comment: Yes, you need to cite it. Yes, it can look a little cluttered, but you need to cite all the sources. I've seen published tables with a dozen or more citations listed underneath.

Comment: Thank you @JonCuster. Yes, citing is of course a must, I was just wondering if there's any other way. But since you've seen tables with multiple sources cited below it, I think it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The MLA Style Center now provides an answer [to this very question](https://style.mla.org/data-table-several-sources/):

> Indicate the sources of your data in a note beneath the table or figure. If that is too cumbersome, give the sources in an endnote placed in the text that introduces the table or figure.